# Is it possible to list all processes which connected to particular ip and port?

Tags: linux, networking, security

I want to list the processes which connected to Particular IP and port. Is there any command to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `lsof`:

```
lsof -nPi @192.168.1.123:443
```

(add `-t` if your only want the process ids).

That lists sockets bound to that address as well.

With `ss` (from `iproute2` on Linux):

```
ss state established dst 192.168.1.123 'dport = :443'
```

With PSMisc's `fuser`:

```
fuser -n tcp ,192.168.1.123,443
fuser -n udp ,192.168.1.123,443
```

However note that it (at least version 22.21 here) won't report the IPv6-mapped IPv4 addresses, you'd need separate queries for those:

```
fuser -n tcp ,::FFFF:C0A8:017B,443
```

(`::FFFF:C0A8:017B` being the IPv6-mapped version of 192.168.1.123).

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at `ss` which is a replacement for the old `netstat`

For example:

```
 ss -atp
```

As root, will list all current TCP connections on the server with processes names and PIDs.

`man ss` for more options.

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

The format is:

```
lsof -i [tcp|udp][@hostaddr][:[service name|port]]
```

E.g.,

```
lsof -i TCP@172.12.1.45:443
```

See [lsof(8)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/lsof.8.html).